# get upload date of all chanel videos with yt_dlp

Tags: python, json, youtube-dl, yt-dlp

it's posible to extract upload date in a json for all videos of a chanel?

i want a json but that the json had the upload date of all videos
here is my code.

```
import json
import yt_dlp as youtube_dl
options = {'ignoreerrors': True,'quiet': True,'extract_flat': 'in_playlist','dump_single_json': True}
def getData(url):
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(options) as ydl: return ydl.extract_info(url, download= False)
dictio= getData('https://www.youtube.com/@4everZyanya')
```

returns a json but in the json isn't the upload date.
but if i write in windows terminal:

```
youtube-dl --get-filename -o "%(upload_date)s" www.youtube.com/@4everzyanya
```

i can get all upload dates
i need it but with python
sorry, my english is so bad.

Answer (score 0):

1.Wrong question format, please fix it.see [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)
2.Whether `youtube-dl --get-filename -o "%(upload_date)s" www.youtube.com/@4everzyanya` is linux shell? If so, you can use the following code:

```
import subprocess
url="www.youtube.com/@4everzyanya"
subprocess.getoutput("youtube-dl --get-filename -o %s" %url)
```

Comment: is in windows, thanx for your help. but in this way the user needs install yt_dlp but i want compile my program.